# JSON Return - key causing error warning

Tags: jquery, json, rest, elasticsearch

I'm getting a set of results back from ES (Elastic Search) in JSON, I'm iterating through this as you expect and printing out the results onto a web page. It's iterating through them fine and working as expected however I'm not sure if there is a hidden problem or something which could be prevented by finding out why this problem is being raised.

The error - (Chrome)

[image: Error message - Chrome]

Any insight on getting rid of this would be great, also does wonders for my OCD...

Thanks.

**Return JSON**

```
{
"took": 16,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 13016,
    "max_score": 9.844111,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "uber",
            "_type": "uber",
            "_id": "RuELvw41S7-3AoBCWKKXBQ",
            "_score": 9.844111,
            "_source": {
                "pty_desig_suffix": "|",
                "pty_forename": "NATHAN",
                "pty_name_suffix": ", |",
                "pty_surname": "SMITH",
            }
        },
```

Comment: Please post the content of `data` as it's returned from the request.

Comment: The data you've posted there is two separate objects? That's not possible in one call. Could you please also post the javascript you're using to loop.

Comment: This isn't the full JSON, its valid, I can assure you.

Comment: are you entirely sure you are not checking an index i that's out of bounds for hits.hits?  In any case - to be thorough - i would do a console.log of hits, hits.hits, hits.hits[i]

Comment: @NSmeef you seem very secretive about your code, which is a little odd. We can't help you if we can't see the full logic of your code, and can follow its path.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'll post it shortly, just a bit busy at the moment. Thanks a lot though. The data itself is protected however my code isn't. Bare with me.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that `data.hits.hits[i]` is undefined. I would log the value of `data.hits.hits[i]` first (and maybe you meant `data.hits[i]` ?). You should probably put a check in place for `data.hits.hits[i] != null && data.hits.hits[i] != undefined`

In any case, if you do:

```
console.log(hits);
console.log(hits.hits);
console.log(hits.hits[i]); // this one only in the iteration
```

you should be able to spot where things are going wrong.

Comment: I'm doing the same search as a test and it always returns the same results and I always get the error, the validation you mentioned above is in place elsewhere.